# Creating HTML Content In a Variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript variable I need to create like this:

```
var HTMLContent = '<div class="className">HTML Content</div>';
```

How can I format it in an easier to read format because I'm going to want to create multiple lines of HTML.

e.g.

```
var HTMLContent = '
<div class="className">
  HTML Content
</div>
';
```

Is something like that possible?

It would also be good if I could import via URL e.g. var HTMLContent = 'http://domain.com/page.html';

Answer (score 10):

```
 var longStr = "You can split\
 the string onto multiple lines\
 like so";
```

An example using your HTML would be:

```
var longStr = 
    '<div class="className">\
        HTML Content\
    </div>';
```

To load external HTML, check out jQuery's [load method](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```

Comment: That's the best way so far, wonder if there is a better way at all.

Comment: This is still not very maintainable over time.  A better approach is to store your template markup as part of your HTML code instead of injecting it in your javascript.

Answer (score 5):

In your page markup, add a hidden template div, like:

```
<div id="contentTemplate" style="display: none;">
    <div class="className">
        HTML_CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

...then in your JavaScript, you can do something like:

```
var newContent = 'The content for the new element';
var templateContent = document.getElementById("contentTemplate").innerHTML;
var htmlContent = templateContent.replace("HTML_CONTENT", newContent);
```

You could also use an [AJAX request](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php) to pull the value of `newContent` from a URL to get your dynamic content loading working.  If you plan on doing this, however, then I suggest you investigate using a framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), which can greatly simplify this process.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use backticks

```js
function myFunc() {
var HTMLContent =`
<div class="className">
    <div>HTML Content</div>
</div>
`;

document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = (HTMLContent);

}
myFunc()
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use escape characters:

> `var HTMLContent = '<div class="className">\n\tHTML Content\n</div>';`

I may have misinterpretted the question, you want the javascript to be more readable, not the html stored in the variable?

Comment: Yes, you're right. He's asking for some way to store easy readable HTML into a javascript variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
var HTMLContent = 
    '<div class="className">' +
    'HTML Content' +
    '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
 var HTMLContent = '<div class="ClassName">' + 
   'HTML Content' +
    '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var HTMLContent = "" +
"<div class=\"className\">\n" +
"    HTML Content\n" +
"</div>\n" +
"";
```

This way, the script that writes it it pretty and the code it writes will be pretty too if someone were to view-source.